# Windows 8.1 boot stuck

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, ssd, thinkpad

Booting system (Windows 8.1) on my laptop (ThinkPad T400) often stuck on screen with Windows logo. I can't do anything but "hard shutdown" by holding start button. Then I start it again and Windows load.

When boot is successful, disk led is active (it is blinking) during the system boot.  But when it stuck it become "dead" and nothing happen. There is just a Windows logo with loading sing.

I have System SSD and also data HDD in additional 2nd hdd caddy. I excluded 2nd HDD from boot in BIOS. SSD seem to be OK, not corrupted. I keep my system updated. I often use docking station but this problem occurs even when I start it separately.

Does somebody have a suggestion how to solve this problem? Isn't it dangerous for system or for my laptop, can it corrupt it somehow-disk, data or something else?

Comment: It seems that my using of shortcut for shutdown laptop produce problems. I made shortcut with command "shutdown -p" I really liked it 'cause it shutdown my laptop in few seconds and didn't wait for anything except Win updates. Now few days I use just Alt+F4 than Shutdown and I think during these days this problem hasn't occur yet. So maybe this was problem :)